# AngularJS ignore require if controller not found in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive using the require attribute with as value : '^myCtrl'

Is there anyway I can catch the error thrown if 'myCtrl' isn't found anywhere ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure about catching the error, but you can make it optional and avoid it altogether:

```
require: '?^myCtrl'
```

Comment: Once you are in the directive, is there a way to check if the controller has been found or not ?

Comment: Yep, the 4th parameter of the link function is the controller. If it's undefined that means you haven't gotten it. (note that you can also specify multiple controllers in the require and then the 4th parameter would be an array)